# List container - storing and removal using unrelated types

Tags: c++

EDIT:

I choose to re-write my entire question and make it more step by step.

So than i would like to store types inside std::list (like ObjectA and ObjectB seen below), where in turn these types must all have member properties which return an expected type (int const* as in this example):

```
class ObjectA
{

public:

    int const* GetItem () {return mpItem;} const;

private:

    int*        mpItem;
    ObjectC     mrObjectC;

}; // class



class ObjectB
{

public:

    int const* GetItem () {return &mrItem;} const;

private:

    int         mrItem;
    ObjectD     mrObjectD;

}; // class
```

So now the two objects above need to be inside std::list as in:

```
ObjectA         nrA;
ObjectB         nrB;

std::list<###   const*> nrRender;

nrRender.push_back (nrA); // comes down to storing ObjectA and ObjectB
nrRender.push_back (nrB); // inside the same list
```

After all this is done. A subroutine iterates the std::list and sends the data for further processing like so:

```
std::list<###   const*> nrRender::const_iterator niObject;
for (niObject = nrRender.begin(); niObject != nrRender.end(); ++niObject) {

    this -> Display ((*niObject).GetItem ());

}
```

Finally i would like to do this also:

```
nrRender.remove(nrA);
nrRender.remove(nrB);
```

Comment: The first part cries out for std::map. The second part is unclear ("keeps pointers"? "HooksInto"?) but might be a job for std::set.

Comment: I'v added some more comments into the second example. I hope that is little more understanding now.

Comment: Can `nrZ.HooksInto(nrB);` also give `nrZ` a pointer to `nrB`?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your code correctly, the `nrZ` object may inspect whatever is passed to it through the `HooksInto` method, and keeps references of inner objects found in that argument.

For instance, if the object `nrB` contains objects `iB1` and `iB2`, `nrZ` can find them and keep references to them by inspecting `nrB`.

The `nrRender.push_back(nrZ)` call let the `nRender` take these references and store them for further processing; however, if `nrRender.remove(nrB)` is called, these references must be removed from the `nrRender` object.

I will assume that the `list` template mentioned in your code is actually `std::list`.

So, `nrRender` can only store values of type `TypeZ`. This is actually a problem in your code. If you want `nrRender` to keep track of `TypeA` to `TypeZ` values, then you must make it a list of the most general type : `TypeA`. However, once a value is pushed in the list, its complete type is forgotten, as illustrated below:

```
  list<TypeA *> nrRender;
  TypeB nrB;      
  TypeA *ptr;

  nrRender.push_back(&nrB);
  ptr = nrRender.pop_back(); // here we're getting back nrB, 
                             // but now it's a (TypeA *) value
```

Also, if you don't make your list be a list of pointer to instances, then you will not be able to hold references to the objects passed in.

Next, the feature you'd like to have isn't available. The `nrZ::HooksInto` method suggests that your objects are build using composition, when you would need them to be constructed through inheritance for the `list<TypeA>::remove` method to work as requested.

If the `list` isn't `std::list`, but some template you would like to implement with the desired features, I suppose this can be done, but I don't see the point of making it a template.

```
 class render_list {

   public:
     /* ... */
     void push_back(const TypeZ &t){
         // get the inner references within t
         // store them in this instance
     }
     void remove(const TypeA &t){
         // remove t
     }
     // overload remove if necessary to handle TypeB peculiarity
     void remove(const TypeB &t){
         // remove t
     }
     // etc.
     void remove(const TypeA &t){
         // remove t
     }
 };
```

Note that it's difficult to provide better guidance without more details on what you are exactly trying to achieve.

Comment: Thank you for your time and your assumptions are correct… I have been searching for the answer most of the day and it appears that I do have a design complexion. I have been looking at pure virtual interface but not sure as of yet it they are my answer... It is a simple idea but difficult to explain, I will append some more code to try explaining what i need shortly.

Answer (score 0):

After battling half day with the compiler, here is solution (the virtual interface and base class working as one):

```
class TypeA
{

public:

    virtual int GetCount () = 0; // The notation =0 simply indicates the Virtual function is a pure virtual function as it has no body

};



class TypeB : public TypeA
{

    string      GetTitle ();

public:

    string      mrTitle;

};



class TypeC : public TypeB
{

public:

    int GetCount () {return 5;}

};



class TypeD : public TypeB
{

public:

    int GetCount () {return 8;}

};
```

Testing the solution:

```
        TypeC           nrC;
        TypeD           nrD;
        list<TypeB*>    nrRender;

        nrRender.push_back(&nrC);
        nrC.GetCount();

        nrRender.push_back(&nrD);
        nrC.GetCount();

        cout << endl << "Ca: " << &nrC;
        cout << endl << "Da: " << &nrD;

        cout << endl << "SizeA: " << nrRender.size();

        list<TypeB*>::iterator niItem;
        for (niItem = nrRender.begin(); niItem != nrRender.end(); ++niItem) {

            cout << endl << "Adress: " << (*niItem);
            cout << endl << "Counts: " << (*niItem) -> GetCount();

        }

        nrRender.remove(&nrD);

        cout << endl << "SizeB: " << nrRender.size();

        for (niItem = nrRender.begin(); niItem != nrRender.end(); ++niItem) {

            cout << endl << "Adress: " << (*niItem);
            cout << endl << "Counts: " << (*niItem) -> GetCount();

        }
```

I hope this will help someone.